# How open mail from letter_opener gem in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, development-environment, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I use the `letter_opener` gem for my app rails in development, and i work on **google chrome** on my macbook but when i create a new user that open the mail in *safari*. Can i **change it to chrome ?**

This is the lines I've add to :

**My gemfile**

```
gem 'letter_opener, :group => :development
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Answer (score 0):

letter_opener uses Launchy, which checks environment var BROWSER. A workaround is setting it
`BROWSER='/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app' rails s`

Comment: where did i need to write this ?

Comment: This is a command to run rails server. here it is the path to my google canary app on application folder.